# Preciso de ajuda porque não entendo por que meu código não está realizando a filtragem por data. ASP.NET [Resolvido]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp

Quando eu faço a filtragem, nenhum valor é retornado para mim

[my view index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vCl3.png)

Acho que o problema está no meu índice ActionResult, mas não sei o que é, porque acho que as referências estão corretas. O que sei no meu controlador de índice é converter a variável DataTime em String

My Model

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Data_Registo { get; set; }
public Programa()
    {
        Data_Registo = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

My Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
    {
        if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
        {
            //this will default to current date if for whatever reason the date supplied by user did not parse successfully

            DateTime start = DateManager.GetDate(startdate) ?? DateTime.Now;

            DateTime end = DateManager.GetDate(enddate) ?? DateTime.Now;

            var rangeData = db.Programa.Where(x => x.Data_Registo >= start && x.Data_Registo <= end).ToList();

            return View(rangeData);
        }
        return View(db.Programa);
    }


    public class DateManager
    {

        static bool IsMonthAssigned { get; set; }



        public static DateTime? GetDate(string d)
        {
            char[] splitsoptions = { '/', '-', ' ' };
            foreach (var i in splitsoptions)
            {
                var y = 0;
                var m = 0;
                var day = 0;
                if (d.IndexOf(i) > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        foreach (var e in d.Split(i))
                        {


                            if (e.Length == 4)
                            {
                                y = Convert.ToInt32(e);

                                continue;
                            }
                            if (Convert.ToInt32(e) <= 12 && !IsMonthAssigned)
                            {
                                m = Convert.ToInt32(e);
                                IsMonthAssigned = true;
                                continue;
                            }
                            day = Convert.ToInt32(e);


                        }

                        return new DateTime(y, m, day);
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
            return null;


        }


        public static DateTime? GetDate(string d, bool custom)
        {
            CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

            string[] dateFormats =
            {
            "dd/MM/yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy", "yyyy/MM/dd", "yyyy/dd/MM", "dd-MM-yyyy", "MM-dd-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd",
            "yyyy-dd-MM", "dd MM yyyy", "MM dd yyyy", "yyyy MM dd", "yyyy dd MM", "dd.MM.yyyy", "MM.dd.yyyy",
            "yyyy.MM.dd", "yyyy.dd.MM","yyyyMMdd","yyyyddMM","MMddyyyy","ddMMyyyy"
        };//add your own to the array if any

            culture.DateTimeFormat.SetAllDateTimePatterns(dateFormats, 'Y');

            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(d, dateFormats, culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var date))
                return date;

            return null;


        }
    }
```

My View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Programas", FormMethod.Get))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend>Search criteria</legend>
    @Html.Label("StartDate", "Start Date:")
    <input class="startdate" id="startdate" name="startdate" type="date" value="">
    @Html.Label("enddate", "End Date:")
    <input class="startdate" id="enddate" name="enddate" type="date" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
</fieldset>
}
```

**(UPDATE)**
Tentei criar uma entrada direta, mas os dados não são carregados do banco de dados

```
        public ActionResult Index(DateTime? start, DateTime? end)
    {

            var programas = db.Programa.Where(x => x.Data_Registo >= start && x.Data_Registo <= end).ToList();

        return View(programas.ToList());


    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Qual é exatamente a sua pergunta? se o banco de dados não está retornando nenhum registro, como você esperar ter algo para exibir?

Comment: A minha base de dados não retorna nenhum registo depois de aplicar o filtro. A pergunta é o que pode estar errado para não retornar nenhum registo? Nota: antes do filtro a BD é carregado certa, só depois de aplicar o filtro é que não retorna nada.

Comment: Faça a consulta na mão, tente outros parâmetros com um range maior. Você pode estar tendo problema de achar resultados por conta da hora junto do da data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente consegui! nada como simplificar
Deixo o código abaixo para quem necessitar de criar uma procura entre datas.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string startdate = null, string enddate = null)
    {
        if (startdate != null && enddate != null)
        {

            DateTime start = Convert.ToDateTime(startdate);

            DateTime end = Convert.ToDateTime(enddate);

            var rangeData = db.YourTable.Where(x => x.YourColumn >= start && x.YourColumn<= end).ToList();

            return View(rangeData);
        }
        return View(db.YourTable.ToList());
    }
```